# Sending Emails Securely - https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Tags: api, google-api, gmail, nodemailer, oauth2-playground

1. Created a google project in  Google Developer Console to have the necessary API credentials.
2. Configured OAuth2.0 API credentials in OAuth consent screen.
3. To get the Refresh token and Access token from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

I got Authorization Error - 403 Access Denied when I tried to Authorize API

Authorization Error
Error 403: access_denied
The developer hasn’t given you access to this app. It’s currently being tested and it hasn’t been verified by Google. If you think you should have access, contact the developer (dummyemail@gmail.com).
Learn more

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps: -

1. Go to console screen
2. Select +Add Users
3. Enter your email in it.
4. Save it and you are good to go.